# when add phone number on Whatsapp cloud API recieve error this whatsapp business account does not have permission to add phone numbers to the account?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

when i try to add phone number on cloud  whatsapp official API i receive error "this whatsapp business account does not have permission to add phone numbers to the account"

error "this whatsapp business account does not have permission to add phone numbers to the account"

Answer (score 0):

To use official Whatsapp Business API you need a phone number, which Whatsapp does not have. If you use a number that you use the app on, you need to delete (not the app, but the number from WhatsApp). And only then you can add it to the Cloud API
In that sense, it's easier to just buy a new number and connect it. Could that be the problem?